# Purpose of obsolete flag for comments

Tags: discussion

What is the purpose of the obsolete flag for comments ? Does that refer to dead links ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question and after looking for references I would say we should use that flag more often.

From: [Is it OK to casually flag comments as obsolete?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156127/is-it-ok-to-casually-flag-comments-as-obsolete/156128#156128)

> After editing the comment is not needed anymore, can it be marked as obsolete?

Answer (higlight added):

> **That's exactly what the obsolete flag is for**. Flag away!
>
> Comments are, by their very nature, transitional. Flagging helps keep them under control and tidied up. Note that **if a comment has been flagged multiple times, it'll be auto-removed**, so you are not overly burdening the moderators when flagging comments, provided we all do our bit.

Conclusion:

1. Flag comments as obsolete that are not necessary anymore because they have been answered or their information is now edited into question or answer.
2. Clean up after yourself: For example, if you asked for the Magento version and got an answer, add the appropiate tag to the question and delete your comment.

Comment: Wow it's actually super useful I didn't think it was for this purpose. Specially when a whole conversation happens in the comments. Cheers