# Why was my flag declined?

Tags: discussion

I flagged the comment on this question because the code was in the question body: [Magento 2 login customer programmatically without password](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132462/magento-2-login-customer-programmatically-without-password/132463#132463)

As stated in [this meta post](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1026/2380), this comment is clearly obsolete but still it was declined with no explanation.

Any reason behind that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I declined it because it appeared in a long list of flags and I didn't read the question the comment was attached to.
It just didn't look like it was anything wrong with it.
You did not get a reason to why it was declined because mods cannot add decline comments to the flagged comments. Only flagged questions and answers have this feature.
I deleted the comment now.

Comment: All good thanks for that I appreciate your explanation