# Flagging comments

Tags: discussion, flagging, comments

I'm writing this as a notice to the person(s) that lately started flagging as obsolete a lot of comments that request the OP to mark an answers as accepted.
Please stop that.
Those comments are not obsolete, even if the OP accepted the answer.
It may serve future readers as a lesson that they should accept an answer that solved their problem.
If you are going for the [Marshal](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/marshal) badge at least flag something that is harmful to the website.

Comment: I just get a hint who is that, also problem with that guy is for duplicate question, some times to much old and accepted posts were  mark as a duplicate with the same  guy.

Comment: I have the same feeling, but I cannot confirm it because for comments I don't see who flagged them. Only for answers and questions.

Comment: I'm not sure this kind of person comes on Magento Meta to begin with, but still worth a try.

Comment: @JulienLachal. I wrote this for 2 reasons. 1. To blow some steam. 2. to have a link to send when I reject a flag.

Comment: Don't you have a way of asking higher instances if they know who has been flagging these comments? I'm sure it'd be easier to deal with.

Comment: It's not worth it. And, since I posted this the flags almost stopped.

Comment: related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182684/flagging-obsolete-comment-conversations

Answer (score 1):

**It wasn't me**, but i've question related to.

Can I flag comments as `obsolete` if the answer was updated or the questioner didn't follow the instructions like

- Updated answer.
- Thanks it works.

Or:

- did you also flushed cache (as written)
- No. Now it works.

Or multible chat invitions (leave last one as comment if usefull)

Comment: What value does this bring to the website?

Comment: If there are just 2-3 comments, I also read them ... if I see a l ot of chatting i do not read it. I see no benefits for keeping Q&A comments. Just talking about really useless comments that have no further information.

Comment: I would rather you not flag comments unless they are spam, begging for upvotes or being rude. Deleting comments might disrupt the conversation flow.

Comment: @Marius is it because this would occupy  moderators and keep them away from more important tasks? Because otherwise, I'd find deleting obsolete comments useful, the value it provides is that readers do not need to read through comments that are not necessary anymore because the answer has been updated. See also: https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/purpose-of-obsolete-flag-for-comments

Comment: Where do you draw the line? How can you know if by removing a comment you don't disrupt the comments conversation. And one more question, how many times do you go through the comments if the answer works?

Comment: I have no intent of disrupting ongoing constructive conversations. But in many cases it's obvious. And I usually read first, before just trying things out. That includes comments, as I expect useful additional information there and not conversation.

Comment: @FabianSchmengler  have the same opinion as of Marius. We flag comments only if they seem some way "destructive". Otherwise, it is perfectly okay to keep the comments. if comments become too much, StackOverflow site is brave enough to direct us to the chat section. So flagging those comments which we feel unwanted may not work for another one (they may feel communication break)

Comment: What value does it bring to keep such comments? Comments w/o any help/content/information. I agree with Fabian, reading through these comments brings no benefit. I flagged comment here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181313/ultimate-multi-flat-shipping-extension-stop-rounding-price as not constructive ... and it was declined. Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Next declined flag here .... https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128399/how-to-get-url-of-product-full-image-with-multistore/182702#182702. This question belongs to another question and was answered there. No need to keep this (useless) comment there ?!? Is there any system to accept/decline flags on comments?

Comment: You're kidding me ... :P

Flagged an exact duplicate comment and it was declined ...  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179472/alter-status-not-send-email/179489#179489

Can someone please explain why dealing with comment flags in another way as flags on questions/anasers?

Comment: because reviewing flags consumes equally much time for answers/questions and comments, but the gain regarding comments is nearly none. So probably someone did not bother enough to look at the full context to see its duplicated and just decided from the single comment, which itself sounds usefull

Comment: Yes, I don't bother reading the whole conversation if the comment does not look like spam, shady or abusive. And I will keep dismissing them until people get the point and stop flagging them. Reviewing flagged comments is even more time consuming than reviewing questions or answers and the value it brings is minimal.

Comment: If it is too time consuming, why not hit the "skip" button? Maybe someone else has time for it? Clicking one button - either skip or reject - takes the same time, but first could be an improvement if someone else takes time to read ...