# Declined 'No Longer Needed' Comment Flags

Tags: support, flagging

I flagged two comments on [a question I came across](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219082/how-to-set-discount-value-in-js-file-magento2), nearly 3 months ago now, and they were declined.

<sub>I've only just been back to notice this.</sub>

The specific comments are [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219082/how-to-set-discount-value-in-js-file-magento2#comment303896_219082) and [this one](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219082/how-to-set-discount-value-in-js-file-magento2#comment303900_219082).

I flagged these as 'No longer required' which seems pretty reasonable to me. The first asks for clarification and the second one confirms the clarification. I also checked the revision history for the post which shows that the OP *did* update their question with the requested information.

These comments now serve no purpose that I can see (nor did they when I flagged them 7 days after they were posted and 7 days after the information was added).

Was there a reason that they *are* still required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They got dismissed mostly because of this: [Flagging comments](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1158/146)
There are a lot of flagged comments that should not be deleted because that would disrupt the ideas discussed in the comments.
I guess your comments got dismissed because they were in a large pool of flagged comments and were overlooked.
I deleted them now.
As a side note...
Comments like that are not really needed, but they don't cause too much noise in the website.
my opinion is that comments should be flagged if they are rude or abusive or have nothing to do with the post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To clarify, I shouldn't be flagging comments which would fall under the 'No Longer Needed' category on Magento? The [flagging privilege page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) has a link to [the flagging guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work/17365#17365) which is what I followed. I don't visit this site very often so I didn't know the local customs. Apologies if this caused extra work! :)

Comment: Yes you should flag them. What I'm trying to say is that "no needed" is a bit relative and you should think twice before the comments are actually not needed and check if removing them does not disrupt the conversation flow. And no need to apologize. I encourage asking questions :)

Comment: Ah, I follow you now, thanks. In this case specifically the flags were good but generally, always check the context isn't ruined. Sorry, I misunderstood that this was a local site policy that I wasn't aware of.